# How do you cook quinoa?

Tags: quinoa

How do you cook quinoa? I mean what equipment do you use (electric cooker, pressure cooker, stove top)? Do you add spices or vegetables to it while cooking it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quinoa naturally contains a bitter compound on the outside of the seed.  Usually you have to rinse the quinoa to remove the bitterness but most commercial quinoa seems to have already been rinsed.  So, I no longer rinse my quinoa.  If you have time, it's nice to heat a pan and add the quinoa and toast it a little (for a nutty flavor and fluffier texture), then add water and salt.  I typically bring the water to a boil (2 cups water to 1 cup quinoa plus 1/4 tsp salt), cover and reduce the heat to a simmer for 10-20 minutes (or until the little tails release).  Lately I've found that using a rice cooker is a no-fuss way to prepare quinoa.  I usually just do quinoa, water and sea salt but you can add spices while cooking it if you want to enhance the flavor.  I would add vegetables afterwards. Quinoa is so quick-cooking I wouldn't see the need for a pressure cooker.

Answer (score 3):

I use it in 3 different ways:

1. "Raw": I put it as a crust for many of my breads, or deep fry coatings.
2. Boiled: I boil it like couscous and enjoy it that way as a rice substitute.
3. Flour substitute: I usually substitute it for flour (max of a 1/2 cup).

Answer (score 2):

I generally

- cover it with water in a saucepan,
- boil it for around 10 minutes,
- drain it

and then use it in the same way I'd serve rice.  I find it tastier than rice and like the texture.  I don't usually add anything, but I'm sure you could.

Answer (score -1):

Good question, Surya. It's interesting to know what kinds of questions others have about quinoa.

Our family cooks quinoa in a **plain stainless steel pot**. No fancy equipment needed.

We usually **throw in some spices while it's cooking**. The best for us are garlic, onion, basil, and oregano.

Then when it's done cooking we'll usually sprinkle some **olive oil** (extra-virgin, cold-pressed) and salt on it.

Finally we serve it with **broccoli and peas** and sometimes **lentil beans**.

We give some more details about cooking quinoa on our page if you're interested -- [How to Cook Quinoa](http://www.quinoahealthylife.com/how-to-cook-quinoa.html).

Hope this helps.